# Rewrite equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a hard time finding a relation between $y$ and $x$ in the following equation:

$\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\frac{x^{3}}{3}=\frac{\pi}{12}$

I tried to split off the $x$ or the $y$, but I feel like it's impossible.
Any help?

Comment: How do you get rid of $arctan$? What is it’s inverse?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\not=0$, we have

$$\arctan\left(y\over x\right){x^3\over3}={\pi\over12}\iff\arctan\left(y\over x \right)={\pi\over4x^3}\implies y=x\tan\left(\pi\over4x^3\right)$$

Note that the range of the arctangent function is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so we must have $|\pi/4x^3|\lt\pi/2$, or $|x|\gt1/\sqrt[3]2$, which is why the second logical connector is "$\implies$" instead of "$\iff$."